# How to include SVG file contents with PHP without XML header and strip some attributes?

Tags: php, xml, svg

The contents of SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" style="enable-background:new 0 0 120 120;" xml:space="preserve">
...
</svg>
```

Currently I am using `file_get_contents()`, but that also includes `<?xml ...>` header. How do I include only the svg tag and also strip some attributes (id, xmlns, xmlns:xlink, xml:space) from it? So the result would be like

```
<svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" style="enable-background:new 0 0 120 120;">
...
</svg>
```

Comment: In that case every question regarding XML parsing is duplicate. All I would like to see is just a simple example which I couldn't find. I am just trying to figure out the best approach. I tried using simple PHP functions like `substr()` to get only the part after "<svg " and of course it worked. But if I have to alter also attributes then it gets more complicated. I also tried to use `simplexml_load_file()` which created XML object and I suppose attributes could be altered there more easily, but when I returned the result with `$xml->asXML()` the header and even the comment was there.

Comment: Stripping `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` removes the namespace. As an XML file it is not SVG any more.

Comment: I suppose I don't need it if I simply include it inline in HTML5. Like you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp)